# -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsnumber

Below is my Response

```
geolocation =         {
        loc =             {
            lat = "22.4409980000000004451976565178";
            long = "70.0686230000000023210304789245";
        };
    };
```

My app crashes when I try below code:

```
NSNumber* n = [userPin valueForKeyPath:@"geolocation.loc.lat"];
NSLog(@"num is class %@", NSStringFromClass([n class]));
float fCost = [n floatValue];
```

When I print my `NSStringFromClass` I get `__NSSingleObjectArrayI`.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess the (runtime) type of `userPin` is array and it contains one element. When applied to an array `valueForKey:`, on which `valueForKeyPath:` is based, returns an array produced by applying itself to every element of the array.

If this is the case either index `userPin` before the call or handle the array resulting from the call.

**Addendum**

> Could you give me an example?

Trivial example:

```
// An array of strings
NSArray *test = @[ @"The", @"quick", @"brown", @"fox"];
// Trivial keypath...
NSArray *result = [test valueForKeyPath:@"length"];
// Print
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Produces:

```
(
    3,
    5,
    5,
    3
)
```

showing `result` is an array of the result of applying `length` to each element of `test. HTH

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: @MihirOza – see addendum